# Not able to register and instantiate Chaincode - Hyperledger Fabric - Blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am working upon a basic Blockchain POC and I have been able to do following:

1. Installed and started the Hyperledger fabric v1.0 successfully
2. I have list of Docker images running on Fabric

hyperledger/fabric-ca, hyperledger/fabric-orderer, hyperledger/fabric-peer, hyperledger/fabric-ccenv , hyperledger/fabric-couchdb

3. I have written Chaincode in go to read and update the ledger and compiled successfully

Next - What do I need to do and not able to do and Where I am confused?

4. Register my Chaincode to a peer – How do I find which Peer I need to register
   I tried to follow this video but it uses YAML and I do not have it and it gives error-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76WIJjKNekY&list=PLz3iwtnWFin-yUUgn-zP7KJp0iW0IFas9&index=2

Also followed few more tutorials but still confused what to do

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html

5. Instantiate my Chaincode
6. Query my Chaincode - I will be able to do it once Chaincode is registered and deployed
7. Invoke my Chaincode to update the ledger - Same as above

Please help in above step or let me know if there is any good source of clear steps to perform registration and instantiation of chaincode.